# Gulp: Getting a lot of errors when compiling typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I have a simple gulpfile that compiles TS and put them in dist folder.

I use node v6.2.0 and tsc v1.8.10.

Everything compiles fine , but i get a lot of errors like:

> node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(7,14):
>   error TS1005: '=' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(7,19):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(8,14):
>   error TS1005: '=' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(8,18):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(9,14):
>   error TS1005: '=' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(9,18):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(10,14):
>   error TS1005: '=' expected.
>   node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts(10,17):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/dashboard",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
const config = require('./gulp.config.js');

const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    lazy: true
});

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(config.dest, { force: true });
});

gulp.task('resources', function() {
    _log('copy - ' + config.assets, $.util.colors.yellow);
    return gulp.src(config.assets, { base: config.root })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    _log('copying libs to:' + config.dest + 'lib' ,$.util.colors.yellow);
    return gulp.src([
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**'
        ], { cwd: 'node_modules/**' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest + 'lib'));
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(config.root + "**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});

gulp.task("default", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    _log('Building the project ...', $.util.colors.yellow);

});

function _log(msg, color) {
    color = color || $.util.colors.blue;
    $.util.log(color(msg));
}

function _logError(error) {
    _log('**** START OF ERROR ***', $.util.colors.red);
    _log(error, $.util.colors.red);
    _log('**** END OF ERROR ***', $.util.colors.red);

    return error;
}
```

How can i get rid of these errors?

Comment: Can you post the code around where the error occurs?

Comment: @2426021684 - what do you mean?, I posted the entire gulp file, and it happens when i run the gulp command.

Comment: Post the first ten lines of `node_modules\@angular\common\esm\src\directives\ng_for.d.ts`

Comment: @2426021684 - it's open source, you can see it here: https://github.com/angular/common-builds/blob/master/esm/src/directives/ng_for.d.ts

Comment: Using npm, install `typescript@next`. Then try again

Comment: If that works I will write an answer explaining why

Comment: @2426021684 - it didn't help, actually it made things worse, I now get considerably more errors

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Readonly is only available is 1.9